# Power grid stability in an only inverter grid

Tags: renewable-energy

I think i there is little misconception in my head regarding the cause and effect of changing grid frequency and therefore I am confused about the transition from fossil fuels to regeneragtive energy supply.

So first: Is the following statement kind of correct?

Today powergrids are, for the biggest part, made out of large generators which all generate the same frequency and are all synched in phase. Either 60Hz or 50Hz dependent on the locale. 
They have that frequency because the steam turning the turbines produces exactly the force wich is necessary to overcome the electromagtnetic force which comes from the load in the powergrid. When the load increases the electromagnetic force increases and therefore you need more steam to produce more force  or otherwise the generator would slow down lowering the gridfrequency.

If i read about gridstability i often read that these big spinning masses are good because they have inertia and will smooth out unpredictable peaks and troughs in the power demand and supply.

But what would a grid solely powered by inverters look like. Wouldnt the frequency always be constant because its generated electronically? What happens when the demand and supply do not match? Wouldnt these grids be even more stable? Arent these spinning masses more like the root of the problem?

I know this is a very complex topic and i guess there will never be a grid with just inverters because it is good to have a mix from multiple energy sources. But when talking about gridstability there often is this argument that we need this inertia in the grid. But maybe we wouldnt need it if there is nothing spinning in the first place.